# Using the Python Big Query API, return only the new rows from the Append disposition?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm using the Big Query python API to run a sql script on Big Query with the 'WRITE_APPEND' disposition to add the results to an existing table.

I achieve this via `bigquery.Client.query()`, accessing the result with the  `result.to_dataframe()` method which currently returns the entire destination table, whereas I'd like only the newly generated rows to be returned.

There are a few ways I could get round this, but I'd like to know if there's a way of only returning the rows appended to the existing table, rather than all the rows in that table.

Comment: I think is not possible to perform this action, note that the [to_dataframe()](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.RowIterator.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.RowIterator.to_dataframe) create a pandas DataFrame by loading all pages of a query. So it's necessary to limit your query if you only want to retrieve the rows appended to the existing table